# How do I declare a namespace alias in a header file, then use it in a source file?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I want to put a namespace alias (ie namespace A = B::C) in a header file so I can use it in source files, but the compiler just tells me that its "not a namespace name". Any thoughts?

This is a very simplified axample of what I'm trying to do...

header file:

```
namespace A{
namespace B{
int getInt();
}
}

namespace AB = A::B;

source file:

#include "header_file.h"
#include <iostream>

int AB::getInt(){ // Error "AB is not a namespace name"
return 123;
}
```

Comment: I guess there's an error in your code. (hint: post come code)

Comment: [This](http://www.ideone.com/4IqxN) might help.

Comment: Its way too big. header: namespace a{int a}; namespace b = a;
source:  int a = b::a; // error?!

Comment: If you can fit the example in a comment, @User, then it's not too big. Edit the question to include a short example that demonstrates your problem. It's even better if you do like Als demonstrated and post a link to the compiler output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the file that declares the namespace in the header file or as the comments say do this:

```
namespace B { namespace C { } }
namespace A = B::C;
```

Comment: or to declare empty namespace just before alias definition

Comment: or just redeclare the namespace instead of including.

Comment: The namespace spans across multiple files and I have.

Comment: That's not a problem, the issue is that its scope doesnt span to source files.

Comment: @user965369 i'm reading your problems and going to state the obvious just in case: the alias will work using this method. 1) you will still have to include the headers you use where you use them. 2) and you will have to make sure the inclusion order is correct.

Comment: I've inc an example - I've done everything you've advised. Its a big project so chances are its sometihng else deaper down.

Answer (score 1):

At the point where you create the alias, the compiler must have already seen the aliased namespace.

Therefore, you must `#include` a file that contains said namespace or you must do this:

```
// "Forward Declaring" the namespace
namespace B { namespace C { } }

namespace A = B::C;
```

Comment: I've done all this the problem is that the scope of the alias isn't carried into the source file.

Comment: Have you tried running the preprocessor over your .cpp file and seeing if something strange is happening?  Maybe you have your `#include` nested in a namespace?

Comment: yeah done all that. D'you know where i can find info on namespace alias file scope? Thanks

Comment: @user965369 The scope of a namespace alias should be the same as any other identifier in your code.  As others have pointed out, it would be really helpful if you would post the smallest code possible that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @user965369 Heck, even the actual error message would be helpful.